# Call Values from JQuery File

Tags: c#, jquery

Hello every one I am having a jquery file. with the following lines.

```
var gridbordercolor = "#eee";
var InitiateChartJS = function () {
    return {
        init: function () {

            var doughnutData = [
                    {
                        value: 30,
                        color: themeprimary
                    },
                    {
                        value: 50,
                        color: themesecondary
                    },
                    {
                        value: 100,
                        color: themethirdcolor
                    },
                    {
                        value: 40,
                        color: themefourthcolor
                    },
                    {
                        value: 220,
                        color: themefifthcolor
                    }

            ];           
            };
            new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(doughnutData);
        }
    };
}();
```

--This is the code in my aspx file

```
                                        <div class="chartcontainer">
                                            <canvas id="doughnut" height="300"></canvas>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

So now i want the values to change using webmethod in my .aspx file

Can any one help me how do I can change these values dynamically.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "change these value dynamically"?  What specifically are you trying to do and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have written web services for the department performance the values are comming in json format. Now I just want to assign these values to the above jquery method. The jquery is from the boot strap template where I have downloaded recently.

Comment: For starters, there's no jQuery being used in the code you're showing.  This is simply called JavaScript.  Also, whatever "web services" you're talking about in that comment aren't mentioned at all in the question, nobody here knows what they are. Aside from that, it's still not clear at all what you're trying to accomplish. You want to use different numeric values than the hard-coded ones here? Then, well, use different ones.  What's preventing you from doing this?  Maybe you can show what attempt you've made and explain how it didn't work as expected to help clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Ok David. I accept your comment. I am asking me to help in that way. may be your awesome in jquery I am just a starter. I am calling the web method in my cs file. and this doughnutData is in different js file. So how can i change it. Iam asking for the syntax purely.

Comment: `"I am calling the web method in my cs file"` - C# runs on the server, JavaScript runs on the client. These are two *very* different things, not just in different files. I'm sure there are a lot of things you can do to accomplish what you're attempting, but until you can help us understand what it is you're attempting there isn't much we can do to help. Maybe you need to output the values from server-side code to the page and use them in this code? Maybe you need to make an AJAX call from this code to fetch the values? Maybe something else entirely? You have to elaborate.

Comment: If i call the web method from ajax post and store the values in json in my aspx file then how can i call the methos from that js file and update those values.

Comment: Considering that the code you've shown doesn't actually *do anything* (it defines a variable, which then immediately falls out of scope never having been used), there really isn't a "right" way to do it because, well, there's nothing to actually do.  You can't access these values, because they cease to exist immediately after they're created.  You *could* make an AJAX call inside this `init` function and define `doughnutData` based on the result of that AJAX call.  It wouldn't change much, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function LoadChart() {
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CS.aspx/GetCustomers",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {                    
                    var data = eval(r.d);
                    golbaldou = data;
                    new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(data);
                    },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }
            });
        }
```

and Adding this function into the main function as shown here has solved my problem

```js
 var InitiateChartJS = function () {
            return {
                init: function () {
                    debugger;
                    LoadChart();
                    var doughnutData = golbaldou;
            ....................
```

Thanks to my friend David who helped me...